# clarify use of ns in packages

Tags: clojure, package, require

Started playing with Clojure yesterday.
I can't get around how the module system works:

1. I have installed cursive
2. I have created a project following the leiningen template
3. I have two clojure files under `/src/clojure_first_steps`

core.clj

```
(ns clojure-first-steps.core)
(:require [clojure-first-steps.utils :refer :all])

(defn run-other-foo
  (foo-2 ["hello"]))
```

utils.clj

```
(ns clojure-first-steps.utils)

(defn foo-2 [x] (x))
```

although 'lein compile' runs without probs, 'lein test' fails to compile on 
`(:require [clojure-first-steps.utils :refer :all])`, the test being:

```
(ns clojure-first-steps.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [clojure-first-steps.core :refer :all]))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "I can access dependecies from another module"
    (is (= "hello" (run-other-foo)))))
```

The error message is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure-first-steps.utils`

EDIT: Project tree

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── clojure_first_steps.iml
├── doc
│   └── intro.md
├── LICENSE
├── project.clj
├── README.md
├── resources
├── src
│   ├── clojure_first_steps
│   │   ├── core.clj
│   │   └── utils.clj
├── target
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── maven
│   │           └── clojure_first_steps
│   │               └── clojure_first_steps
│   │                   └── pom.properties
│   ├── repl-port
│   └── stale
│       └── leiningen.core.classpath.extract-native-dependencies
└── test
    ├── clojure_first_steps
    │   └── core_test.clj
```

Comment: Could you please show output of `tree .` in your project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your core.clj:

`(ns clojure-first-steps.core)
(:require [clojure-first-steps.utils :refer :all])`

This is incorrect - the `(:require)` clause needs to be inside the `ns` macro. Because it is not, the symbols in the vector are looked up (and obviously not found).

```
(ns clojure-first-steps.core
  (:require [clojure-first-steps.utils :refer :all]))
```

This tells the Clojure compiler to load `clojure-first-steps.utils` (if it has not already), and refer it's definitions in your newly created namespace.